# File globbing in Ruby and Unix

Tags: ruby

I have the following directory structure on my desktop:

```
sample/
  a.rb
  b.rb
  c.rb
  sub_sample/
    blah.rb
  whatever/
    meow.rb
```

Unix globbing behaves as expected in bash:

```
Desktop $ ls sample/*.rb
sample/a.rb sample/b.rb sample/c.rb

Desktop $ ls sample/*/*.rb
sample/sub_sample/blah.rb   sample/whatever/meow.rb

Desktop $ ls sample/**/*.rb
sample/sub_sample/blah.rb   sample/whatever/meow.rb
```

Apparently, the last example will recursively glob, similar to Ruby, if [globstar is enabled](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/bash4).

Here is how the globbing works in Ruby (last example produces the different output):

```
>> Dir[Dir.home + "/Desktop/sample/*.rb"]
=> ["/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/a.rb", "/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/b.rb", "/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/c.rb"]

>> Dir[Dir.home + "/Desktop/sample/*/*.rb"]
=> ["/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/sub_sample/blah.rb", "/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/whatever/meow.rb"]

# This is the recursive output that I don't understand
>> Dir[Dir.home + "/Desktop/sample/**/*.rb"]
=> ["/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/a.rb", "/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/b.rb", "/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/c.rb", "/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/sub_sample/blah.rb", "/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/whatever/meow.rb"]
```

When more than one star is used, it behaves the same as the single star:

```
>> Dir[Dir.home + "/Desktop/sample/***************/*.rb"]
=> ["/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/sub_sample/blah.rb", "/Users/powers/Desktop/sample/whatever/meow.rb"]
```

Here are my questions:

1. How does `**` recursively search through all the folders?  I think of `*` as something that matches anything of any length.  Is `**` interpreted as something entirely different (like a method)?
2. Are there any other ways to recursively glob in Ruby?  It seems like `/**/*` is the 'standard' way to glob in Ruby, but the syntax is a bit confusing for me.  Hopefully I can get more comfortable with it when I figure out what `**` is doing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying `Dir['path/**/*.rb']` is, more or less, like saying:

```
find path -name '*.rb'
```

from the shell. So with Ruby's [`Dir`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html), a `**` glob searches the specified `path` and all directories under `path`. Apparently bash's `**` only looks at directories under `path` without looking at the files in `path` at all.